# SelectNav Capital Case when creating

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this page: http://cirkut.net/sub/avid/

In my HTML, my menu items are capital case (Home, About, etc.), but I text-transform them to lowercase (my branding uses lowercase primarily).

I'm using `selectnav.js` for a responsive menu, and I love how it works, but I'd want the `<option>`'s in the select to be the original capital case.  Apart from altering the plugin, is there an easy way to have `selectnav` use the actual HTML (capital case) rather than the rendered text (lowercase)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can target the `.selectnav` element and capitalise it with CSS.

```
.selectnav {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Comment: I did this immediately after posting and realized it works, but only if the page is loaded at the size where selectnav is used. I'm using this for now, but would like to maybe find a more wholesome solution.  The only thing I can think of that would be foolproof would be to set the text to lowercase AFTER the selectnav call, but I'm not sure that's so graceful.